# CMIS Query error

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I want to know all the folders name under "Company Home" directory in Alfresco but getting error.

Code -

```
ItemIterable<QueryResult> results = session.query("SELECT * FROM cmis:folder where IN_TREE('/Company Home')", false);
try {
    for (QueryResult result : results) {
        folderId = result.getPropertyValueById(PropertyIds.OBJECT_ID);
        Folder folder = (Folder) session.getObject(folderId);
        System.out.println("Folder Name " + folder.getName());
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Error -

```
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: 00270668 Request failed 500 /solr/alfresco/cmis?wt=json&amp;fl=DBID%2Cscore&amp;rows=100&amp;df=TEXT&amp;start=0&amp;locale=en_US&amp;fq=%7B%21afts%7DAUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&amp;fq=%7B%21afts%7DTENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:452)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.post(AbstractAtomPubService.java:570)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.DiscoveryServiceImpl.query(DiscoveryServiceImpl.java:142)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl$3.fetchPage(SessionImpl.java:567)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.util.AbstractIterator.getCurrentPage(AbstractIterator.java:132)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.util.CollectionIterator.hasNext(CollectionIterator.java:48)
    at main.java.org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.doc.QueryTest.folderName(QueryTest.java:180)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IN_TREE takes the object id, not the the object path. If you provide the id of the "Company Home" folder, this query should work.

Comment: Florian, Can you please let me know where I'll get syntax info for CMIS query. I did not get much info on Apache site.

Comment: The query chapter of the CMIS 1.1 specification is here: http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/cs01/CMIS-v1.1-cs01.html#x1-10500014

Answer (score 1):

Company Home is the root folder, I suggest you use something like the following:

```
    Session session = createSession();

    Folder rootFolder = session.getRootFolder();

    ItemIterable<CmisObject> children = rootFolder.getChildren();

    for (CmisObject child : children) {

        System.out.println(child.getName());

    }
```